# gcloud recommender usage doubts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to use the gcloud recommnder command to get all the recommendations in the Organization.
So far I have it working for specific projects with the following code:

```
gcloud recommender recommendations list \
--recommender=google.compute.instance.MachineTypeRecommender \
--project=servers-prod-mine \
--location=us-east1-c
```

But there are way too many projects...
According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/recommender/recommendations/list)
I should be able to replace --project variable with --organization variable. So I tried

```
gcloud recommender recommendations list \
--recommender=google.compute.instance.MachineTypeRecommender \
--organization=390900123456 \
--location=us-east1-c
```

but that gives the error

> ERROR: (gcloud.recommender.recommendations.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT:
> Request contains an invalid argument.

I also tried with --organization=mydomain.net but it gives the same error.

EDIT: thanks to DazWilkin, and using "--verbosity=debug" got to the following:

> DEBUG: https://recommender.googleapis.com:443 "GET
> /v1/organizations/390900123456/locations/us-east1-c/recommenders/google.compute.instance.MachineTypeRecommender/recommendations?alt=json
> HTTP/1.1" 400 None DEBUG: (gcloud.recommender.recommendations.list)
> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.

Looking at the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.recommenders.recommendations/list), the structure and parameters seem fine. I even tried calling the API REST URL using Oauth Playground and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Does ` gcloud organizations list` include an (organization) with ID `390900123456`?

Comment: If it does, perhaps try adding `--verbosity=debug` to your command

Comment: Thanks, updated the question with results of debug info

Comment: Which organization-level roles does the identity have (the one that the CLI is configured to use)? https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#recommender-roles As test add this role to the identity at the org level: roles/recommender.computeAdmin

Comment: It's curious that the error is `INVALID_ARGUMENT` suggesting that the issue is with `gcloud`. Are you able to `gcloud organizations list` to return that org? I am able to run the same command (Linux and latest `gcloud`) without that error. Can you try reordering the flags, i.e `--organization' before `---recommender`?

Comment: It is not an issue with gcloud, but rathe the API. Using Oauth Playground I get the same error.  John, I have Org Admin and Editor at the Org level.

Comment: Have you tried this command? ```gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_PROJECT_ID --member "serviceAccount:NAME@YOUR_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/owner"```
since you are having an "ERROR: (gcloud.recommender.recommendations.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument."